# ivy:resolve with explicit resolver

Tags: ivy

I have two resolvers configured. One is the company repo, the other a local developer repo. 
I want to:

```
<ivy:resolve  />
<ivy:install from="company" to="local" ... />
```

it is essential, that the first resolve goes directly to the company repo and collects all needed modules.

Problem: I can't force resolve to use a explicitly defined resolver. I tried using "modules" in my settings File, but then I only get some modules from company, the rest is still read from local (which is empty at the time, so I get resolve errors).

I can use 2 settings-files, one for preparing and one for local development, but there has to be a better way. Why can "publish" set a resolver, but "resolve" can't?

Comment: How have you declared the resolvers, in your settings file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can "publish" set a resolver, but
>   "resolve" can't?

Resolve absolutely can.  This is typically done through multiple settings files as you mentioned you didn't want to do.  In practice, I find it very common (if not standard) to have more than one settings file used in conjunction with the `settingsRef` property of the resolve call.

In our project we do something along the lines of:

```
...
<target name="init-ivy" depends="">
    <ivy:settings id="install.settings"
                  file="${project.ivy.config.dir}/ivysettings-install.xml"/>
    <ivy:settings id="internet.settings"
                  file="${project.ivy.config.dir}/ivysettings-internet.xml"/>
    ...
</target>
...
<!-- note init-ivy has already been called before this target runs -->
<target name="resolve-internet" if="internet.connected" >
        <echo>"internet connected! Resolving dependencies via internet..."<echo/>
        <ivy:resolve settingsRef="internet.settings"
                     haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="resolve.failed"/>
</target>
...
```

Of course, in a simpler project, you can alway have the "main" settings file get called automatically (either by placing it in the root directory or editing the ivy property `$ivy.settings.file`) so you only use the "install" settings when running the install target.

Comment: OK, I give up. I switched back to the multiple settings you suggested, whiche leaves me dealing with the "unknown resolver error" unless I clean caches between resolve with setting-A and resolve with setting-B. Was hoping for a better way, but this works for me.